# Post Request With Headers

Tags: c#, python, request

So I wrote a program to send a POST request in Python, and I've been having alot of trouble trying to do the same thing in c#. I've been searching for about ~2 hours now and just am coming up empty handed. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
url = "https://www.example.com"

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; 
rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0"}

data = {"example":"test",  "example2":"test2",  "example3":"example3"}
r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)

Comment: @John Yes ive tried the methos in this thread and it did not work.

Comment: Then provide a [mcve]. If it didn't work, you're doing something wrong. Without seeing your code, we can't tell you what that is.

Comment: What is the error that your code is throwing? Looks ok at first glance...